Independent Black And White Film. Ends Due To Film Equipment Being Stolen
A man is unhappy with his life so he decides to film everything and then review the footage to figure out what is going wrong with his life. His friends think this is a bad idea since people don't act like they normally would in front of a camera. When his approach of "filming stuff will fix my life" doesn't seem to work, he starts filming more and he starts to alienate the people in his life. Like his girlfriend dumps him for filming her while she slept and he also starts filming a woman from across the street. He also films another woman who is sitting on the same subway car as him and refuses to stop when she asks him to. He even follows her when she leaves, which prompts her to run and he then chases her. The movie abruptly ends with a title card saying that he cannot film anyway due to someone stealing his film equipment.

The B&W drama David Holzman's Diary from 1967, an early mockumentary (and found footage) film.

This fake documentary which appears quite real on the surface is about a young man making a movie about his everyday life and discovering something important about himself and his reality. This film is not a real documentary or is it?

The scenes you described are there, and it ends when the film equipment is stolen.
